# How to write the Batch Apex using Last Modified By (Account object) in salesforce?

Tags: batch

Here iam using Account object had the field of Last Modified By.how to write the Batch Apex can you please give me the example of above scenario.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm

`QueryLocator` query =>

```
Select Id, Name from Account Where LastModifiedBy.Name='John Smith'
```